# Dados medidos num intervalo de 5min - Qual linguagem de prog. usar?

Tags: característica-linguagem, estrutura-de-dados

Trabalho com medições automáticas de 5 em 5min numa base de dados, conforme ilustra:

[image: estrutura dados no excel]

Eu geralmente utilizo o Excel para fazer análises (soma, média, distribuição, etc.). Entretanto, devido ao grande volume de dados, cerca de 500mil linhas, o excel não dá conta do processamento. 
Gostaria de elaborar um aplicativo que faça apenas as análises que necessito, mas não sei qual seria a forma mais correta de armazenar os dados (csv,txt,mysql,etc.) nem qual a linguagem de programação a mais indicada para tratamento de dados deste tipo.

Gostaria da opinião de vocês.

Comment: Compreendo bem que neste momento ainda não tem nenhuma base de dados, somente excel? De onde vêm as os dados/medições? que tipo de contas quer fazer?

Comment: Somente excel e arquivos .csv . Estes dados vem de dataloggers que monitoram sistemas de energia solar e estações meteorologicas.

Comment: E como chegam os dados ao computador? via internet, ficheiro, ou escritos à mão?

Comment: Um ficheiro para cada mês, onde cada ficheiro tem um arquivo para cada dia, por exemplo: C:/Janeiro/ tem os arquivos: 01-01-2014.csv, 02-01-2014.csv, ...

Comment: R é uma linguagem interessante para trabalhar com analise de dados.

Comment: Não invente a roda , existem software estatísticos como SAS ($) e R (free).

Comment: Muito obrigado pessoal, vou dar uma pesquisada sobre as opções que vocês forneceram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu trabalho com CSV's que possuem grandes tamanhos, como 10Gb, 12Gb e por aí vai. Basicamente eu uso Python com algumas bibliotecas que me ajudam em performance e facilitam algumas operações, dá uma olhada:

Pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/
NumPy: http://www.numpy.org/

Comment: É possível criar aplicativos como c# e VB com Python? Grato.

Comment: Não. São coisas bem diferentes.